# Can't center title because of social media icons?

Tags: html, css

I have put social media icons on the right side of my html, but I can't center my title anymore, how can I fix this?

I've tried `text-align: center` already, and it doesn't work.

```css
#socialm{
  float:right;
}
#socialm ul li{display: inline;}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="socialm">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><img src="facebook.png" width= "45px" height="45px"/></a>
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com" target="_blank"><img src="instragram.png" width= "45px" height="45px"/></a>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/..." target="_blank"><img src="youtube.png" width= "45px" height="45px"/></a>
  </div>
  <h1>Photography and visual arts</h1>
</header>
```

Comment: h1{text-align:center;} ??

Comment: 1. your question tags are incorrect (title - you have no actual title in your example, center - might be the answer for your question but currently I see no 'center' tag, 'icons' - not related at all). 2. missing css files, we don't see in your code how you are trying to center your header. 3. "I can't center my title anymore" - what does it mean? is it aligned left? right? describe your problem better.  please edit your answer and tags, and add relevant css code to get better help.

Comment: Your HTML has an error... You're have multiple closing brackets for you youtube attribute.. `</a></a>` But that has nothing to do with your problem ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this without absolutely positioning one of the elements.

Absolute positioning takes the element out of the flow so it ignores the other elements around it.

Here I positioned the 'social' div on the right instead of floating it. As you can see the heading is now centered.

You can also see the downside of positioning..without careful sizing, you get overlap. Media queries can address this.

```css
#socialm {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
#socialm ul li {
  display: inline;
}
header {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="socialm">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/96/140.jpg" width="45px" height="45px" />
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com" target="_blank">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/96/140.jpg" width="45px" height="45px" />
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/..." target="_blank">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/96/140.jpg" width="45px" height="45px" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <h1>Photography and visual arts</h1>
</header>
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/2u87j2zL/)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but I simply just added `text-align:center;` to your h1 tag.

Here is the solution:
http://codepen.io/Glenvig/pen/dMeaQm

Comment: I wan't to center it on the screen. This doesn't ignore the icons and centers it from the beginning, to the first icon...